# How to approve "Unapproved caller" whilst installing the software?

Tags: macos, install, error

I'm trying to install [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io/), but it fails with the message:

> Unapproved caller.
>
> SecurityAgent may only be invoked by Apple
> software.

[image: Unapproved caller. SecurityAgent may only be invoked by Apple software.]

How do I approve the caller or get rid of that error? What this error actually mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems it's some kind of temporary glitch, as it usually helps to restart the machine.

Other suggestions:

- Reboot into [Safe Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564), then Verify and repair drive

  1. Reboot and hold the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys
  2. Select Disk Utility
  3. Click on the image under my drive
  4. Verify and repair drive
- You may try to remove the cache files/folders located in `/var/folders` directory (not recommended) or move them into Trash.

  Normally cache files should be cleared every few days by Launch Daemon (/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.bsd.dirhelper.plist).

  If the files can't be removed, reboot into [Single Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564), run `fsck`, mount the root partition and run `rm -vR -- /var/folders/*`. Which is:

  1. Start on single user mode: Hit the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keys at start-up
  2. At the line, type (after root): `fsck -fy` and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
  3. Mount the root drive by: `mount -uw /`
  4. Remove the cache files by: `rm -Rf /var/folders/*` (make sure you won't do any typo!).
  5. Reboot by typing: `reboot`.

Comment: When I run `rm -Rf /var/folders/*`, I get "invalid argument" ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried many online suggestions. My situation was different, I had trashed the content of hidden var/folders/ after seeing a post that said it was all leftover junk from earlier flash updates. Turns out Mavericks needed something and was very unhappy and determined to teach me a lesson. Would not let me use TM to recover. I solved it by booting using computer #2, Target Mode and Onix (show hidden) so that I could copy the files out of computer #1 trash back to the hidden file.